# Custom logic in code-first EF6 SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator not working

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I am trying to set the default value SQL for  a computed column called 'Duration' in a table 'dbo.Table1', in code-first Entity Framework 6 migration through SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator class.

I tried setting this in Generate methods for AddColumnOperation as well as for CreateTableOperation. While the code under Generate method for column never fires, but the code under Generate table fires and throws an error saying the following. (the column EndTime is a column in table dbo.Table1 and so is StartTime)

> The name "EndTime" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions
>   are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

**Question**: How could I make this work in either of the Generate methods in code below?

```
        internal class CustomImplForSqlServerMigration: SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator {
        protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation) {

            base.Generate(alterColumnOperation);
        }
        protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation) {


            if (addColumnOperation.Table == "dbo.Table1" && addColumnOperation.Column.Name == "Duration") {
                addColumnOperation.Column.DefaultValueSql = "(CAST(CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME) - CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) AS TIME))";
            }
            base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation) {


            if (createTableOperation.Name == "dbo.Table1") {
                foreach(ColumnModel cm in createTableOperation.Columns) {
                    if (cm.Name == "Duration") {
                        cm.DefaultValueSql = "(CAST(CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME) - CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) AS TIME))";
                    }
                }
            }
            base.Generate(createTableOperation);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE 1**:

I used another simple approach to add my custom logic for modifying database objects using ExecuteSqlCommand. Just follow the steps below to use this in your situation.

- come up with the custom script for modifying or creating a database object
- execute a command in Seed method for every custom script
- make sure that the ExecuteSqlCommand statement is placed at end of Seed method and also context.SaveChanges( ) method is called before the code for custom scripts in case there is a dependency on seed data

  ```
  protected override void Seed(EfCodeFirst.ShiftsDb context)
  {
     //Write your seed data statements

     //call SaveChanges in case your custom script depends
     //on some seed data
     context.SaveChanges();

      //include your custom scripts like ALTER TABLE 
      //or CREATE PROCEDURE or anything else
      //use a ExecuteSqlCommand for every custom script
      context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE ShiftTypes DROP COLUMN Duration; 
       ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD Duration AS (CAST(CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME) - 
        CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) AS TIME)); ");

  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a limitation of EF but of the database itself - you cannot refer to other columns within Default value specification. What I would recommend you instead is to write stored procedure for inserting new Table1 entities and then map with fluent api according to [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx).

Comment: In DefaultValue, I cannot refer to other columns, but in DefaultValueSql, it should be possible.  What I ended up doing is adding this code at end of 'Seed' method: context.Database.SqlCommand(" ALTER TABLE TABLE1 DROP COLUMN Column1; ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ComputedCol AS (some SQL expression);")

Comment: But I was hoping I could run the same SQL from within one of the overidden methods of SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator class.

Comment: Better not do this in Seed as Seed is called always when db is migrated to newest version, even when no migrations are applied. So your sql will be executed over and over again. To avoid this store this code in migration. If you would like to be able to have this with usage of SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator  you may write your own class inheriting from SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.

Comment: Are you sure that your sql command from comment works? I just tried it in MS Sql Server and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, in my case it certainly did as the value of the column was populated after update-database command was run as I viewed table data. One thing I did was that just before this SQlCommand, I made sure to call context.SaveChanges( ) method else I was also getting an error. And most important, write these custom scripts SqlCommand code at end of Seed method.

Comment: It should work. I actually used this approach for creating stored procedures also. It has always worked for me. Make sure to put a check in your script to check for object in database if your script is using CREATE script else you will end up with an error when that object exists.

Comment: I have explained how to do it using SqlCommand under UPDATE 1 in my original post.

Comment: Thank you. But still having this method stored in Seed will cause it to be executed over and over again and probably will cause exceptions during migrations of db. Take into account Seed is called each time db is migrated :)

Comment: That is correct. In my situation we were not following an incremental approach, so it works great always. But let's say that you were using an incremental approach, then you would include checks in your script that would prevent your script from executing if the stored procedure already existed. But things like dropping a column and re-creating it will always succeed provided the table exists. If you follow this approach, then it will be executed again and again, but will not give you any errors.